# How to take a part of an output, without knowing the result

Tags: python, networking, ip

I have a command that scans for devices on a network then give a lot of info about them including it's ip address, how to isolate the ip and convert it to a string ? 
Knowing that it scans for specific devices, something like nmap won't work for my case, plus, there will be multiple IPs, how to isolate them in different strings ?

Output :

```
[{'ip': u'xxx.xxx.xx.xx', 
  'port': xxxxx, 
  'capabilities': {
      u'hue': u'0', 
      u'color_mode': u'2', 
      u'name': u'xxxxxx', 
      u'power': u'on', 
      u'support': u'get_prop set_default set_power toggle set_bright start_cf stop_cf set_scene cron_add cron_get cron_del set_ct_abx set_rgb set_hsv set_adjust set_music set_name', 
      u'rgb': u'16712469', 
      u'fw_ver': u'44', 
      u'bright': u'100', 
      u'model': u'stripe', 
      u'ct': u'2000', 
      u'id': u'0x0000000005e1c8db', 
      u'sat': u'100'
      }
  }]
```

Comment: Is that the output you want, or is that the output from your scanning command?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy The command is from https://yeelight.readthedocs.io/en/stable/yeelight.html#
I am making a GUI to command the bulbs

Comment: @PM2Ring It's the output of the command

Comment: @PM2Ring not even - the OP says "command" but that's really a python function (yeelight.discover_bulbs) which returns a list of dicts. The op copy/pasted the printout of the function's return value.

Comment: @Mazeo you should read some basic python tutorial for data structures. Best start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are receiving parsable output can simply do:

```
ips= []

for data in output:
    ips.append(data["ip"])
```

Or as comment suggest:

```
ips = [data["ip"] for data in output]
```

Comment: Or even simpler : `ips = [item["ip"] for item in output]`

Comment: Why "decode" ? You don't decode unicode strings (you eventually want to encode them but better to keep everything unicode within the code).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers opsies. Was answering another question :) got inputs confused

Comment: And how to do for the name ? I managed to get "port" working but not "name"

Comment: names = [data["capabilities"]["name"] for data in output]